# Support legacy code without access to compiled code behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have been asked to support a legacy app and I can't get access to the code behind files. I need to add a new feature that gets a list of items from the database on page_load, what way would adding an "in-page" page_load affect the compiled page_load?

What would be the best approach to take with this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that the legacy app has a Page_Load I assume it's .NET.  This means that you should be able to decompile it using [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) from Redgate to get the original source.

The source will likely be much less "pretty" than it was originally, but you should be able to get editable, compilable source out of it.

As for the question of an in-page page load and a compiled page load - You can try it... But I doubt it will work.  You're really better off trying to get the source if you can.

Comment: Previous developer is awol and I am trying to avoid rebuilding up the source code as it will have an associated cost for the client which I amsure they won't want to pick up.

I was thinnking of using jQuery ajax calls, would that be a good solution?